# Polymer 1.0 - Issue selecting dynamic element by id

Tags: javascript, web-component, polymer-1.0

I am trying to select an element by id that was created dynamically:

```
<dom-module id="filter-box">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <template>
    <h4 id="title">{{title}}</h4>

    <paper-checkbox id="test">test</paper-checkbox><br>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{filters}}">
      <paper-checkbox id="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-checkbox><br>
    </template>

  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  (function () {
    Polymer({
      is: 'filter-box',
      properties: {
        filters: {
          type: Array,
          notify: true,
        },
        title: {
          type: String
        }
      },
      ready: function() {
        this.filters = [
          'Commercial',
          'Enterprise'
        ];
      },
      isSelected: function(filter) {
        return this.$$[filter].checked;
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

When isSelected("something") is called I get:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined"
```

I can select the title  via this.$.title, however I can not select the dynamic elements this way or using this.$$ as suggested [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the reference you provided you are supposed to call `this.$$(selector)` with **parentheses** as in a function call (and not with brackets). So replace your code with this:

```
return this.$$('#'+filter).checked;
```

Note that you may also need to prepend the id selector with `#`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this.$$(...) is still returning undefined.

Comment: Have you tried `this.$$('#'+filter).checked;`? Id selectors start with `#`.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the '#' was implicit.

Comment: It's not implicit because it's a CSS style selector and as such it can be a tag name, class name, etc.